# How do i put the other java number triangle side by side

Tags: java, numbers

So i was trying this code i found on the internet that let me make number triangles, the codes are like so

```
public class StarsAndDraws {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 4; j >= 1; j--){
                
                if (j > i){
                    
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    
                } else {
                    
                    System.out.print(i - j + 1);
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 
}
```

the output looks like this

```
      1
    1 2
  1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

but this is the output im looking for

```
               1
             1 2
  1        1 2 3
1 2      1 2 3 4
```

i have no idea how, help and explanation is appreciated because id like to do this to other kinds of stuff aswell

Comment: So what exactly is your question? And what have you tried to make it work in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To print first `1/ 1 2`, it is needed to define another loop for that one too.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      if (i < 3) {
        System.out.print(" ".repeat(9));
      } else {
        System.out.print(" ".repeat((4 - i) * 2));
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 2; j ++) {
          System.out.print(j);
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ".repeat(6));
      }
      System.out.print(" ".repeat(2 * (4 - i)));
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j ++) {
        System.out.print(j);
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey i tried to use this .repeat but it doesn't seem to work(?), i tried googling it but i ended up with nothing so anything that i can add to make it work?